# FlutterIcon error: Invalid params: - data.config is required (undefined)

Tags: dart, flutter-layout

I tried to "Download" data from **FlutterIcon** (https://www.fluttericon.com/).

**What I had tried to do:**

1. Select Icons
2. Write "AppIcons" in "MyFlutterApp"
3. Press button "Download".

Then I got this message: *"Invalid params: - data.config is required (undefined)"*

Comment: facing the same problem too, I guess its their webapp

Comment: Me too. I've created an issue in their git repo.

Comment: It's now back!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this service to convert svg to font
https://icomoon.io/app/#/select/font

1. click on +import icon
   and after that converted
2. create dart file that contain class with attribute of
   IconData(int,fontName), the int take it from the site

or in setting icon on right of download button you can check generate dart class for flutter